# optimal down payment estimation in credit scoring

Tags: predictive-models, optimization, risk, credit-scoring

Knowing I can estimate the risk of default, via logistic regression, of a consumer on a small loan...

what would be the best way to estimate the optimal down-payment amount to ask for in order to reduce that risk ?

Comment: How do you propose that the downpayment is related to risk?  How exactly do you define "risk" in this context, anyway? By it do you mean the chance of default or perhaps do you mean the *expected value* of the loan, or maybe even the variance of the value?

Comment: There are so many details missing, it's impossible to answer the question. If you talk about down-payment, it means that the loan is collateralized. What is the collateral? What is the recovery rate on default? Do you assume that downpayment amount does not impact borrower's behaviour? etc.

Comment: My question arises because I was rather supposing that my estimation on the behaviour of the consumer (PD at t=t0) would change if he accepts to perform a downpayment (PD at t=t1). So, I thought a naive solution was to take downpayments as a feature in my model for PD and then consider the coefficient that multiply the downpayment value, as the coefficient, e.g. dx that define the relationship. So, if want a PD<0.1, then I should have a downpayment of X such that dx*X decrease PD to 0.1. Is is a correct way of doing ? Nothing better ? I don't suppose collateral neither at the moment.

Comment: maybe I am missing a point here...if I am working with loans that are not collaterized, is there another word in english than "down payment" for a first payment necessary for the contract to be issued ? I thought prepayment is not correct as it relates to a payment to close the contract before its expected end ?

Comment: @Serge I understood that as such, but it might be possible that down payment in US is related to some sort of specific schedule for payments.

Comment: This is hard to address. 1. even if your model predicts well, it's correlational. I.e. does not estimate the causal effect of what happens if you change the required downpayment. 2. This would likely change the number of customers & other loan conditions (low downpayment = few customers, unless something else is more attractive e.g. interest; too little = more customers but perhaps riskier). 3. What are you optimizing? Overall company profit? Because, clearly, you run the lowest risk on each loan, if you only take customers with incredibly low risk, but then you have a very low volume.

Comment: Also note that downpayments in the past were set according to some criteria (that probably correlate with other loan terms like interest, property value etc.) that will impact the extent of variation in downpayment (i.e. your model will not have seen as much variation as you'd like).

Answer (score 0):

Down payment might not directly reduce risk but it might reduce risk of loss when customer is in default.

In international risk management framework for the banks, usually called Basel setting, things are governed by the following eq.

Expected loss= Prob of default (PD) * Loss given default (LGD) * Exposure at default (EAD)

where PD is your risk estimate for individual. It is a probability that one defaults.

It might be that LGD is affected by the down payment.

If PD is affected, then it might be a result via some sort of selection mechanism.

I have seen some results where LGD is a function of PD and collateral (C) and LGD is affected by collateral in following way:

LGD=1-RR(C,PD)

where RR is recovery rate.

NOTE:

-Added an explanation concerning Basel framework

Comment: @whuber no. Basel setting is international regulatory framework for risk management in the banking sector. Link: http://www.bis.org/publ/bcbsca.htm

Comment: @Serge then you have only PD and EAD components. Can these depend directly on down payment?

Comment: My question arises because I was rather supposing that my estimation on the behaviour of the consumer (PD at t=t0) would change once he has performed a downpayment (PD at t=t1). So, I thought a simple solution was to take downpayments as a feature in my model for PD and then consider the coefficient that multiply the downpayment value, as the coefficient, e.g. dx that define the relationship. From there, if want a PD<0.1, then I should have a downpayment of X such that dx*X decrease PD to 0.1. Is is a correct ? Nothing better ?

Comment: @Serge, down payment is a factor in PD, on the other hand PD impacts your decision on down payment. So, you have the simultaneous equations here.

Comment: @Analyst, this basel stuff is for term loans, and it's so simplified. Typically loans have periodic payments, and a borrower may default at any period. Basel only wants to get an estimate of the minimum capital requirement. You'd be crazy to use Basel formulae for valuations or risk based pricing.

Comment: @Analyst Re: "some sort of selection mechanism": it appears that you wonder whether Oscar Wilde's aphorism "A bank is a place that will lend you money if you can prove that you don't need it" can be quantified and incorporated into a model.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos yes, that was what I was thinking. +1 for the funny quote.. :)

Comment: @Aksakal This equation gives you only expected loss, it is not itself yet useful for pricing of risk. And EL is not enought, you have to have some sort of extra risk buffer. If you have non collateralized consumer loans, then EAD will be function of time having highest value at the start of period. There are other things at work here also. Can we believe LGD and PD will not change as time progress?